# Swift 5: How can i get data from JSONDecoder().decode?

Tags: json, swift, decode, jsondecoder

I get JSON from Google translator API:

```
{
    data =     {
        translations =         (
                        {
                detectedSourceLanguage = en;
                translatedText = "\U0434\U0430\U043d\U043d\U044b\U0435";
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Then i do this:

```
     if data != nil && error == nil {
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
        
            let translated = try! decoder.decode(Data.self, from: data!)
            dump(translated)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

And i fetch this:

```
MyVocabulary.JSONTranslator.Data
  ▿ data: MyVocabulary.JSONTranslator.Data.Translations
    ▿ translations: 1 element
      ▿ MyVocabulary.JSONTranslator.Data.Translations.TranslatedText
        - detectedSourceLanguage: "en"
        - translatedText: "Работа"
```

My structs:

```
 struct Data: Codable {
        
        struct Translations: Codable {
            
            struct  TranslatedText: Codable {
                var detectedSourceLanguage: String
                var translatedText: String
                
                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
                    case detectedSourceLanguage
                    case translatedText
                }
                
                init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                    self.translatedText = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .translatedText)
                    self.detectedSourceLanguage = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .detectedSourceLanguage)
                  }
            }
            var translations: ([TranslatedText])
        }
        let data: Translations
    }
```

how can I get properties from TranslatedText to var in "do" block after decode?

Comment: x = r + √(2yr - y²) and x = r - √(2yr - y²)

Answer (score 2):

The major mistake is to name a custom struct `Data` because it interferes with the Foundation struct `Data` and decoding `Data.self` fails.

You don't need a custom initializer nor CodingKeys, these 3 structs are sufficient

```
struct Root: Decodable {  let data: Translations }
struct Translations: Decodable { let translations: [TranslatedText] }
struct TranslatedText: Decodable { let detectedSourceLanguage, translatedText : String }
```

Now decode `Root.self` and get `translatedText` as described below

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let translated = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data!)
    let translatedText = translated.data.translations.first?.translatedText
    print(translatedText)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided is not valid. I will assume you meant the JSON to be something like this:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [
                {
                    "detectedSourceLanguage": "en",
                    "translatedText": "\U0434\U0430\U043d\U043d\U044b\U0435"
                }
        ]
    }
}
```

You don't have to put a `CodingKeys` enum or an `init(from:)` unless you want custom JSON decoding. You can make it simple by letting the default decoding happen automatically.

Modify your model to this:

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    var data: Data
}

struct Data: Codable {
    var translations: [Translation]
}

struct Translation: Codable {
    var detectedSourceLanguage: String
    var translatedText: String
}
```

Inside your `do` block, you should not force unwrap the `try`. You should change `try!` to `try`, this way when the try fails, it will trigger the `catch` block. Otherwise it will crash the app if you use `try!`

Inside `do` you can say:

```swift
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
    let data = response.data
    let translations = data.translations
    let firstTranslation = translations[0]
    let detectedSourceLanguage = firstTranslation.detectedSourceLanguage
    let translatedText = firstTranslation.translatedText
}
```

Comment: The JSON is not the equivalent of the dictionary dump in the question. The value for key translations is an array.

Comment: JSON is exactly what I posted, if it was what you wrote it would be easier

Comment: @VovaKotsiubenko I edited my answer to make translations an array. `JSONDecoder` is powerful enough to decode an array of objects from JSON to `Array`